# Transferring SQL Jobs from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone tell me what the most efficient way to transfer SQL Jobs from SQL Server 2005 to sql 2008.  I'm currently upgrading my sql servers to 2008.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try [SMO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.script.aspx). It will generate a script that you can run to your new instance. Or try it manually: 
 hit F7 key after selecting the Jobs folder, it will bring up the summary pane and from there select the jobs you want and right click - >Script